# I have created a jssor slider, that scales well but kind of flickers when displayed on an iPhone 4S

Tags: jssor

I have created a jssor slider, that scales well but kind of flickers when displayed on an iPhone 4S both in landscape and portrait but is fine on an iPad. I suspect it's hitting the limit of scaling or some such issue.

Also any idea on how to centre the slider vertically.

The URL is www.anamacdonald.co.nz/2.html

Answer (score 0):

Please place your slider in the wrapper below,

```
<div style="position: fixed; display: table; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">
        <div id="slider1_container" ...></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Or you can use $('#slider1_container').css("top", top); to set top of slider1_container to change position manually while window resize.

Comment: Any Idea why the slider does not work on an iPhone but works on an iPad?

Comment: Is it performance issue with iphone 4? There are more than 30 images in your slider. Please test with less images. Also, please try to set $HWA to false.

Comment: Also, please compress your image to smaller size.

Comment: It works fine on Jssor.com. My version works perfectly on my Computer, the slider scales as the window is reduced. My version works fine on an iPad. However when you look at my version on an iPhone both in landscape and portrait you can see the selection buttons, and arrow buttons but no image except a quick flash of the image in transition. It does this on iPhone 4S and iPhone 5 & 6.

Comment: Would you please do the following 3 test cases? 1. Reduce image number from 31 to 3. 2. Compress your image size from 400+ to 100-. 3. Set $HWA to false.

Comment: Also, please move the slider out from your page and make a simple page to have a test.

Comment: And please make sure you are using the latest version of jssor slider.

Comment: Reduced images to 3, no change. Reduced size of images from 400K to 100K, no change. I cannot find $HWA anywhere in the code, please advise.

Comment: I only downloaded jssor a week or so ago, the version I am using is jquery-1.9.1.min.js.

Comment: var options = { ..., $HWA: false, ... };